# android Map image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I am developping a weather android application which displays the temperature of each city of a given country on a Map. So, I would like to use "Map image" but I have not clear idea: how I can locate the cities of this country on this "Map image", generate an event when a click on a city ...
Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Clarify what is 'map image'. Are you using you own mapping library or Google Maps or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Map to achieve it. follow [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). Its clearly explained.

Comment: I'm not going to use Google Map. In fact,

Comment: I'm going to develop this weather application for one specified country. So, I prefer to use an image wich represents the Map of this country and displays on it the temperature of each city. This link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe) may explain more this idea, but I didn't find tutoriels that can clarify that more for me.