# Android set oval button clickable only on image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm trying to find a way how to set clickable regions on oval button. As you can see on the image attached below, Android put the images/backgrounds of buttons in square and if I want an oval button and click on the square where the background is transparent I'm still pressing the blue button, not the green one. I need to be able to set that square as oval maybe..or even some other shape so I can use `onClickListener` only when I press the image.

I hope I explain it correctly! Anyone who has an idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Use RelativeLayout to put a transparent circle shape above the area you want to click on, and handle the events from this shape.

Comment: Yeah, but I still have that square which i want to remove so I can click only on oval image.

Comment: Why don't you remove the button at all? If you are using the circle shape for click event, than you don't need the button.

Comment: Actually I need the image to be there. I've tried to set it as background of relative layout, but it's the same situation.

Comment: Set your image in an ImageView and "cover" it with a transparent shape. Than set listener for the shape.

Comment: I would recommend this method: [Make a clickable map image with each country producing a different action](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4942812/2455518).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the following way: create own view; in the onTouch check if the coordinates are in the region you want and if so call the onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

I think u need to put android:background="@null" in your ImageView tag... Or crop that image to oval shape then put it Resource..

Answer (score 0):

I think if the background of your oval button is transparent.

It can achieve.