# How to click at a certain location that fits for all phones?

Tags: android

[image]

How can I make it so I can click on each of those little images like the carnival, park etc and then something will happen but it will work on all phone sizes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe

Comment: I looked at this but how would I say open a new Activity when clicked on that certain thing?

Comment: @Dalton Do you not have experience opening activities? If you can detect the touch of something, you can just put the activity-starting code within that listener. If you don't have experience opening activities or using touch listeners, this is not a good place to start.

Comment: Lol, Of course I have the experience of doing that. I ment how can I get the location of each place on the picture and tap it and then do something. But it also works on each phone screen