# Android Tap on background and have it zoom in

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to click at a certain location that fits for all phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204999/how-to-click-at-a-certain-location-that-fits-for-all-phones)

So basically I want it so I tap on my certain area and when I tap it it will zoom into a certain area in the background picture

[image]

This is my image

Basically if you click on the playground it will zoom into that area.

How can I do this?

Comment: This looks like [exactly the same question as you already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204999/how-to-click-at-a-certain-location-that-fits-for-all-phones-android-java).

Comment: No, that was asking to get the location of each. this is asking to ZOOM in on the desired spot.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you can post that shows what you have attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Might I simply suggest the classes [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)?