# Want to get information about a particular area in an image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am developing an Android app in which I need to implement the following implementation.

suppose I have an image displayed on the screen (assuming to be a car),now then if I touch any part of the car ,suppose the wheels ,then it should display on the screen "The wheel" or something like that,similarly for other parts as well.

How to do that in android.
What I have tried

I can display the image using image view .

I have the X and Y coordinates of the points am touching.
I am clueless now,what should I do next ??

Comment: do you know the images beforehand or are they new images each time?

Comment: There will be one image only.

Comment: Not, exactly the same thing, but probably enough for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getLocationOnScreen()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29)

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int[] values = new int[2]; 
        view.getLocationOnScreen(values);
        Log.d("X & Y", values[0] + " " + values[1]);
        if(values[0] == Your_Point.x && values[1] == Your_Point.y) {
            // Apply your action..
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes.. and u can check if that point is what u r expecting for.. then apply ur action

Comment: but i have already my coordinates point .
what i want next is if i touch any particular area (e.g the wheel of the car),then the screen should display "Its the wheel" or something like that

Comment: The problem is I need to describe a complete area not a particular point.Any other idea ,do update.

Anyway thanks for the help.