# Android ImageView Overlay textview in given area

Tags: android, bitmap, overlay, android-imageview

I am trying to build a custom View such that it has image and certain area of the image where I need to have a text. For example draw map of a country and overlay certain region like "East", "West" and have text overlay on the given region. 
The reason I want it to be custom view is so that Image can be scaled in different size screens and image is placed in appropriate place.
Similar to Image Map:
I found multiple ways,
[Android: how to make a clickable map image with each country producing a different action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe)

http://catchthecows.com/?p=113

Any other simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Place the map and the textview inside a RelativeLayout and the textview will appear to be overlayed on the map. You can then adjust the position of the textview programmatically.