# ImageView set shapes for click listener

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

Is there a way to create different clicklisteners on a single ImageView ( big image ) ?

If i put an image whit a car i want to have one click lister if i press on the car hood and another click lister if a press on car door.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: u need to break the big image to small parts and then set each part as single imageview, there is no such thing

Comment: what if i put the big image on and then add over some kind of frame define by coords in a relativelayout? is this possible ?

Comment: you can put different  clickable transparent views above each part of the big image that you want to make it clickable and handle the click of the views and not the image, but u have to be careful handling the UI with different screen sizes

Comment: Can you point me an example of a transparent view define by coords ? Thanks for replay

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe

Comment: thanks :D it's a good point to start