# How to make a a background image clickable in some different parts (like a map)

Tags: android, image, background, mapping

in my Android app I use a background image and I need that it can be touchable in some different parts, like a classical html mapping. When I touch a specific part of the background image I need to call an activity, when I touch another specific part of the background image I need to call another activity too. How can I make this ? If it's not possibile with a background image, It's ok to make it with a simple fullscreen image, but I need to use only this because I can't add other separated images. Thank you

Comment: take a look this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to see and I will inform you if I will resolve !