# How to use image mapping in Android?

Tags: android, imagemap

I have a floor plan images and my requirement is to perform a task when clicking on a particular area. or is it to possible to create floor plan like this in android.

I find some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe) but don't understand anything is there any easy solution available for this?

[image]

Comment: Googling "floor plan create in android github" and see results.

Comment: do you have your "floor plan" in some vector graphics like svg?

Comment: no, I don't  have svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a perfect solution I find [ClickableAreasImages](https://github.com/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages) library. I just have to define x,y co-ordination and it allows me to click on that area with zooming and scrolling functionality.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to create an image mask by using another image and coloring each section using different color. Create two `ImageViews` in your layout. Set visibility of the second `ImageView` to invisible. Then use an `OnTouch` listener to get color of the touched pixel. The color will correspond to a predefined area. Here is a tutorial that will help you [link](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/)

Answer (score 0):

i understand you need suggestion to achieve your requirements , i would make movable object with transparent background and solid border to mark the spot a user want to locate , then upon click event on the needed spot a confirmation  message should appear as well on this stage  there is two scenario's you can do here
either you pop up a window form asking the user to insert details about the marked spot or you can  set that @ the beginning during the map plane upload by dividing into static parts , when the marker object get into any spot of defined you can retrieve it's information through matching it with sliced part .

you can use phonegap technology to do that , it will help you speed up the work
beside that you can connect to remote db easily and there is already libraries on phone-gap can open /import auto cad files .

phonegap technology is platform created by adobe , it will allow you to make native mobile application for ios , android and windows , the great thing about it is you can use html / javascript  on it ,after finishing the work the phonegap will generate the apk (ANDROID) , ipa (IOS) files for you as native application .
i searched using npm and i found like 5 plugs for auto cad which can read auto-cad files directly as dwg ...

[click here to view it](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=autocad)

here is adobe phone-gap official plugins library

[click here to view it](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)

even to make this more easier for you , you may use this platform development called alpha software which simplify your life on development & the  working deployment proccess to upload your apps to google play / apple store with phonegap.  you can even upload on your own store using alpha software .

here is video libraries for alpha [click here to view it](https://videos.alphasoftware.com/vam_video_grid.a5w?__browserflags=%7B%27supportsTouch%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27supportsMouse%27%3A%20true%2C%20%27isTablet%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isSafari%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isMobile%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isWebKit%27%3A%20true%2C%20%27isOpera%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isFireFox%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isIE%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isWindows%27%3A%20true%2C%20%27isIPhone%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isIPad%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isXoom%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isKindle%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isPlaybook%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isGalaxy%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isTouchPad%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isAndroid%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27userAgent%27%3A%20%27Mozilla%2F5%2E0%20%28Windows%20NT%2010%2E0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%29%20AppleWebKit%2F537%2E36%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Chrome%2F68%2E0%2E3440%2E106%20Safari%2F537%2E36%27%2C%20%27isNotWebKit%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27useBasicScroller%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27isPortraitMode%27%3A%20false%2C%20%27iOSVersion%27%3A%20-1%7D&componentName=vam_video_grid%2Ea5w&componentAlias=&componentType=A5W%20Page&style=MobBlue&overrideSettings=body%2Estyle%2Ebackground-image%3Aurl%28%22images%2Fwhite_leather%2Epng%22%29)

its called alpha software , i have used it and still using it for over 10 years. 
it can accept any web language such as html , html5 , js as for db it may work with almost all available DB's such as access , mysql , sql , oracle , mango db ,  here is a link for alpha software

https://www.alphasoftware.com/

Comment: I'll try PhoneGap

Comment: please provide GitHub library link