# How to create a Clickable Map for given PNG map?

Tags: javascript, html, clickable

I just wanted to build a Clickable map like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ayCv.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe

Answer (score 1):

In HTML there are so called `HTML Image Maps`. They offer the functionality you are looking for. For an introduction take a look at this article [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp), for a generator use [this](https://www.image-map.net/) link for example.